# Mongodb is giving connection errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I have the MongoDB up and running and after some time of working perfectly fine, it throws the error mentioned below. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
Just ran the code again and MongoDB was able to connect. Not sure why this is happening.

```
failed to connect to server[test - shard - 00 - 02 - ocunf.mongodb.net: 27017]on first connect[MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to test - shard - 00 - 02 - ocunf.mongodb.net: 27017 closed
at TLSSocket.<anonymous>(D: \dev\contactkeeper\node_modules\mongodb - core\lib\connection\connection.js: 352: 9)
at Object.onceWrapper(events.js: 288: 20)
at TLSSocket.emit(events.js: 200: 13)
at net.js: 586: 12
at TCP.done(_tls_wrap.js: 478: 7) {
    name: 'MongoNetworkError',
        errorLabels: [Array],
            [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: { }
}]
```

Comment: Can you post your code of how you're connecting to DB..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Mongo Atlas. You should whitelist your IP address: Security => IP Whitelist. Hope this helps.